# Want to take data from one form to use them as variable in an other

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm almost done doing a Connect4 game with VS2012 using WinForms. Everything is working well but I wanted to bring the options for the user on a dedicated Start Menu window. On that menu I have two comboBoxes I need to take the text from to use them as a value for two variables in my other form (the game window). I also have one New Game button that should call a method from my other form if that's possible (basically, I made an "Initialization()" method in my game form and I'd like it to be launched when I click the "New Game" button on the other form).

I only found tutorials that show how to do very basic things from one form to an other (such as labeling texts) but I I didn't find an answer to my specific problem.

I used this in my main form to instantiate the menu form

```
public FormMenu myMenu;
myMenu = new FormMenu();
```

What I want to do is that I could do something like this in the other form :

```
amountOfRows = Int32.Parse(myMenu.comboBoxRows.Text);
amountOfColumns = Int32.Parse(myMenu.comboBoxColumns.Text);
```

Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Hi, @Morgoth . First off, welcome to StackOverflow... note that usually questions should always have some code attached to them. Right now it's impossible to suggest a good approach because we don't know what your code looks like. There are a number of solutions, the simplest revolves around having static variables in a class accessible by both forms.

Comment: thx for your answer. I added a bit of code in my original post to be more specific about what I want to do.

Comment: You can access public members of your FormMenu, as long as it's in scope. This is a bit more complicated than using a static variable in your parent class, but it is a bit better.  formMenuInstance.someMember will give you the member

Comment: Also, part of asking good questions is being able to break it down to the simplest blocks... which is what you should do with SO questions... just make a simplest example that replicates your issue to post here.

Comment: OK I'll keep that in mind, I'm new over here so I dont really know how it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the instructions are pretty clear... just make sure you put some effort into things if you want others to put effort into helping you...

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see some example code so I can help see where your confusion lies. WinForms requires the other form to be instantiated.

```
OtherForm form = new OtherForm();
```

Once the form is instantiated you should be able to run code from it.

EDIT:

Based on your implementation I would suggest making public methods within FormMenu that return these int values.

```
public int ReturnRows()
{
    return Int32.Parse(myMenu.comboBoxRows.Text);
}

public int ReturnColumns()
{
    return Int32.Parse(myMenu.comboBoxColumns.Text);
}
```

Then from the other form in which myMenu is instantiated you can call myMenu.ReturnRows() and myMenu.ReturnColumns()

Comment: Sorry for not adding code right away. In fact since I do'nt really know how to do that I dont have a lot of code related to this specific problem. I instantiated the menu form in my game form (my main form) already, but from there I don't really know how to do what I wanted to do (that I explained in my first post). I edited my first post with the short code I used to instantiate.

Comment: Thanks, your methods in your edit part worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store a reference to your form in the menue as a variable. (you already named it `myMenu`)

Then you should create the property/properties you need in the form an add a setter for the values. (see example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property))

Last you update the form fields with

```
myMenu.property = newvalue;
```

That`s all about it